# Achieve Apple TV collectionview horizontal infinite scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, apple-tv

im trying to achieve the horizontal scroll, with the new layout of the apple TV.
Already tried to use table view with multiple collection views inside each cell, but since the interaction is not the same with apple tv, i can't keep focus with the cell and the, cell inside the collection view.

Now im trying to create a collection view with multiple sections, but so far, my collection view has two sections and scrolls horizontal, but the  result is not the same.

Does anyone have a better approach to that?

Thanks

[AppleTV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRPJu.jpg)

[My CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPz5Z.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to get the results you want using either UITableView or UICollectionView. I have implemented a horizontal infinite scroll using UITableView. It is a complex UI to develop and I do not have details for where you are having difficulties, so here are some general tips:

Each row is implemented as a UITableViewCell that contains an infinitely scrolling UICollectionView that spans the full row width (but no more).

Be sure to prevent the table view cell from becoming focusable (override canBecomeFocused). The product cells in the row should become focusable instead.

**Set the UICollectionView scrollDirection to horizontal to allow infinite horizontal scrolling**. This may be the most important detail.

Beware that with a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView, minimumRowSpacing and minimumInterItemSpacing have opposite meanings, which is counterintuitive. So **collectionView.minimumRowSpacing** sets the horizontal spacing between products in a row.

Use UICollectionView.contentInsets to set your row's horizontal margins (and alternatively vertical margins as well)

**On UITableView vs UICollectionView**

As mentioned each horizontally scrolling row is a UICollectionView, but you can achieve the vertical layout using either UITableView or UICollectionView. Each implementation has advantages + disadvantages.

UITableView's primary advantage is that it automatically adds top + bottom fade out gradients while scrolling, which is quite nice. UICollectionView does not.

UITableView's primary disadvantage is that it automatically adds 14px of space between any two rows. This behavior is undocumented and unchangeable. If this is a deal breaker, use UICollectionView to lay out rows instead.

Code for UITableView implementation is cleaner. UITableView is simpler for defining rows. Also when using UICollectionView for both vertical layout and for each horizontally scrolling row, UICollectionView callbacks become more complex because they get called for both horizontally scrolling rows and the UICollectionView that implements vertical layout.